# Accessing paramters from the request string in YII?

Tags: yii

Let's say I have the following view:

```
http://localhost/site/www/index.php/products/view/1
```

Then

```
Yii::app()->request->getUrl() ==> /site/www/index.php/products/view/1 
Yii::app()->getController()->id ==> products
Yii::app()->getController()->getAction()->id; ==> view
```

How do I access the "/1" part?

Comment: where do u want to get the "/1" part? In a controller?

Comment: Yes, in the controller... in this case, called "ProductsController.php"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to get the id values.
Let's say you defined the following rule for the Url:

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
```

Then you can get the value of ID by using GET method in php:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Or u can define in your controller a param for the method, the param will automatically be the id u need:

```
public function viewAction($id) {
    //here $id is equal to $_GET['id']
}
```

Be careful, the name of these parameters must be exactly the same as the ones we expect from $_GET

- http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url
- http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller#action

Comment: Hmmm. It looks like I might be going about it the wrong way. How would I then eventually make the url something like products/view/iphone ? or even better: /iphone ?

Comment: in config/main.php u could put the following rule: '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<product:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>' and then in youur controller function you add the param $product.In <product:\w+> the "w+" means that the last arguments in the url can be a string

Answer (score 1):

You can access it as a **$_GET** variable using:

```
$_GET['id']
```

How you ask? Because of the rules set up in the Yii default config (protected/config/main.php)

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
```

That rule specifies a *{controller}/{action}/{a value, named id}*.
You can customize these rules to whatever you want, read more  about it here:

- http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url
- http://yiitutorials.net/easy/easy-url-rewriting-with-yii